# Adjectives after noun: " in a layer high"

Tags: adjectives, word-order, relative-clauses

I can't figure it out why we put 'high' after noun 'layer'. What does it mean? When can we use adjectives after nouns? Is there any difference in the meaning if we swap the position of the adjective and noun in the example above?

> **ozone**
>   a form of oxygen that is found **in a layer high** in the earth's
>   atmosphere.
>   [Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/ozone)

Comment: "a layer **which is** high in the earth's atmosphere"

Comment: @JonMark perry well done for spotting the erroneous addition "called ozone". The sentence now makes greater sense.

Comment: English Learner you must properly cite quotations, and include the source. Next time, I will downvote! :) I see you have asked the [same question](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-form-of-oxygen-that-is-found-in-a-layer-high-in-the-earths-atmosphere-called-ozone.3317791/), including the same erroneous addition, elsewhere on the Internet.

Comment: Taking the words out of context and saying 'layer high' introduces the problem, as the words mean little just hanging high...and dry.

Answer (score 2):

We can use preposition phrases to postmodify noun phrases.

In the Original Poster's example, the verb *find* takes a Locative Complement the essential core of which is *in a layer*. This Locative Complement explains the location of the oxygen.

Now within this preposition phrase there is the noun phrase *a layer*. The Head noun in this noun phrase is being postmodified by another preposition phrase *in the earth's atmosphere*.

This preposition phrase is *in the earth's atmosphere* is being modified by the 'flat' adverb *high*. So the full preposition phrase here is *high in the earth's atmosphere*. The word *high* belongs with *in the atmosphere*, not with the noun *layer*

The structure of the Locative Complement therefore is:

- in [a layer [high in the earth's atmosphere]]

We can paraphrase the sentence like this:

- a form of oxygen that is found in a layer which is high in the earth's atmosphere.

Here is a sentence with a Locative Complement with the same structure:

- We went to a location high in the mountains.

Comment: Interesting. This sounds right now that I have read it, but my first thought was that "high" was an adjective modified by a pp. Is there a way to show that it isn't?

Comment: @sumelic Let me see. Well, if *in the earths atmosphere* was a modifier of *high*, then by definition it would be omissible - but if we leave *high* without the PP, the larger locative complement will be ungrammatical --> *we found it in a layer high*. On the other hand, if we omit *high* the larger phrase is just fine *we found it in a layer in the earth's atmosphere* - seeming to show that *high* is a modifier of the smaller PP.

Comment: I think the reason "high" can't go after the noun is because it is a single-word adjective phrase. It can come before: "a high layer"

Comment: @sumelic Ah, I see. Plausible. Hmmm. Let me think. Perhaps you're right. In fact, probably you're right. I was thinking of it more as a modifier like *far* in the phrase *far below the horizon*.

Comment: @sumelic Pete  I'll do some research tomorrow and let you know what I find out ... I'm waivering (but moving strongly back towards my original analysis).

Comment: @AraucariaMan I completely agree with your answer, but if I didn't see sumelic's first comment below your answer I probably wouldn't have thought of it. Why can't we think of *high* as an adjective, and *in the earth's atmosphere* is a complement of the adjective *high*? I understand you already answered that but you were explaining why *in the earth's atmosphere* is not a modifier. Why am I asking is I don't have any answer to this. (Btw +1 from me).

Answer (score 0):

Adjectives before the noun are called **attributive**.

Adjectives after the noun are called **predicative**.

Sometimes this doesn't matter:

> The red house
>
> The house is red

both describe a house that is coloured red.

Sometimes it does.

In your case:

> a layer high

could be the only layer, whereas:

> a high layer

implies there are other layers in the atmosphere.

Comment: " ... a form of oxygen that is found in a layer high." is ungrammatical. " ... a form of oxygen that is found in a layer high in the earth's atmosphere." involves a standard Whiz-deletion. // Adjectives modifying and positioned immediately after a noun (eg 'chicken _supreme_') without say a link verb are known as 'postnominal' or 'postpositive' adjectives.

Comment: this is the source:http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/ozone ; Unfortunately I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: Just because a noun has an adjective doesn't mean that there's more than one of the noun. Consider *"the bright moon shone down on the wide sea."* That doesn't mean the scene is set on Mars. There has to be more than one layer pretty much by the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/layer) of *layer,* and not because *layer* is modified by the adjective *high*.